# How to handle multiple inputs in a single prompt window?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I've created a button using TinyMCE in the Wordpress Editor window to enable the user to add shortcodes easily.

Currently, I'm making three **prompt();** calls to take three inputs from the user. Can this be done in a single prompt window where the user can enter all the required information ?

```
 ed.addCommand('addcredits', function() {
 var ctype = prompt("What do you want to add (Source/ Via) ? "),shortcode;
 var clink = prompt("Link?"), shortcode;
 var cname = prompt("Link Name"), shortcode;
 shortcode = '[credits link="'+ clink +'" type="' + ctype + '"]' + cname +'[/credits]';
 ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, shortcode);
  }
```

Comment: You can if you use [jQuery UI dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form). But naively no.

Comment: I would not recommend running to jquery to solve this. If it is a simple use case, you don't need the weight of jquery. Designing a simple popup form is actually pretty simple

Comment: Agreed, try something from a UI framework, or create your own *modal-like* UI element. [Twitter Bootstrap](getbootstrap.com) is my personal favorite.

Comment: @BrettWeber He's using wordpress, compared to that jQuery hardly has any *weight* at all. There is no need to do something which has already been done.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Any idea how I should solve this ?